# Excluding certain folders when building PhoneGap aplication

Tags: android, cordova, build, apk

I have built a PhoneGap app for Android. Under `www/` I have some folders, I use when developing my app. I want to exclude these ones, when building the `.apk` file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your platform specific files to the `/merges` folder.

For example, if you have a set of files you want to be packed for iOS only, you can place them under
`/merges/ios/www/my_folder/my_files.*`

This also works if you have 1 CSS with 2 variations for each platform, you can have them as:

```
/merges/android/www/global.css
/merges/ios/www/global.css
```

You can read more about `merges` [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).

Comment: cordova supports the merges folder, but phonegap CLI (and thus build.phonegap.com) still doesn't :(