# Exclude folder, when building application through PhoneGap Build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I keep both source code and test files (in `tests` folder) for my PhoneGap application in one repository. I build my application through PhoneGap Build, by providing link to my repository at GitHub. I'd like to exclude `tests` folder from built application, since its contenst aren't required by application and contains nearly 5 MB of files, which highly enlarges application size.

Is this possible, when using PhoneGap Build only?

<sub>Note, that I'm asking about PhoneGap Build (cloud), not about local build. So neither my question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22201898/1469208), nor [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22213462/1469208) suits me.</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file named `.pgbomit` in any directories which you want excluded.

More info [here](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/11/phonegap-build-adds-some-new-features/#pgbomit) and [here](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_getting_started.md.html).

Comment: I sure wish this worked with the CLI and not just PG Build! This would be so helpful and simple (I just don't "get" hooks yet).

Comment: @ChrisEmerson post your feature request to the [Apache Cordova Issue Tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB/)... or even better send a pull request to the [cli source repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/).

Comment: I submitted something here - here's hoping they throw a (CLI) bone my way.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8527

Comment: @wildabeast .pgbomit is applicable for cordova as well? or is there any other file for ignoring folder/file in cordova?